# Getting "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI" While trying to use MS Graph APIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have used MS Graph API(MSAL) in one SAP Ui5 Application and have implemented Mail api, Calender api and MailboxSetting apis so far. It was working fine till Nov 2020 (Last checked in Nov 30 2020).

Suddenly this application keeps throwing the error "{"error":{"code":"MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI","message":"REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox."}}".

Though we have not changed a single code or any changes has been done in Azure portal or in the envirmental set up.We do have a Hybrid envirment mailbox set up.

The strange thing is the same APIs are working in MS Graph Explorer but not from our custom Apps. But when we use the token generated by Graph Explorer, APIs works from our custom apps also.

We compared the both tokens using [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms). Scopes and other attributes are the same. Only 'wids' attribute is not present in our custom App's Token(We are using Implicit Grant flow).

1. which flow do MS Graph Explorer use, so it works there ?(If Authorization
   flow is the issue).
2. Is it that only Graph Explorer is allowed to make API calls to On-Premise
   Mailbox and the custom applicationa are not?
3. Is there any other factor, we should consider to solve this ?

Thank You,

Arpita

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when trying to access a mailbox that is not hosted in EXO. Check where your target mailbox is hosted and use auto discover to locate the right endpoint for that environment.